# How to set first item selected by default when making a url request?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using uiKit framework.
I am using stack view and inside that are buttons, and data of that buttons is coming from server. I want that when i receive data, first button in stack view will be selected by defalut and the color changes.
can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to set isSelected to true something like this `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
            self?.button.isSelected = true
   }`

Comment: But how to mention that it is the first one selected in stack view? @ReinierMelian

Comment: You need the first button selected or select always first button in the stackView?

Comment: I need that first button be selected by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the first view that is a **UIButton** and then set his `selected` property to `true`

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
        if let button = self?.stackview.arrangedSubviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton {
            button.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: @developer did this answer works for your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution is perfect for me. @Reinier Melian

Answer (score 1):

```
// When you got data from URL request

if let _button = stackView.arrangedSubviews.first as? YourButtonClass {
    _button.isSelected = true // or your custom logic,..
}
```